# Make image fit width of container but not beyond width of image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display photographs so that they fit the full width of their container, unless the container is wider than the image, in which case I just want the image displayed in its actual size and centered.

I am using Bootstrap (and PHP if required to do this)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with just the CSS max-width property.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwboow63/1/

Answer (score 0):

To center de images you should use `text-align: center` for the containers.